# If I claim to have excellent verbal skills on an "additional information" section, is it OK to list a standardized test score as proof?

Tags: hiring-process, applications

Would it be acceptable to list a high score (99%+ percentile) on a standardized test that I took recently in the  "additional information" section? Or is it tacky in this case?

UPDATE: I searched online, and it looks like... yes it's unnecessary and tacky/weird.

Comment: On an application? Sure. If they have a spot in the form for it.

Comment: "tacky/weird" is a good description. You can supply it as evidence if challenged on the claim of excellent verbal skills, but I wouldn't put it on your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you talk to a recruiter in the interview, your "Excellent Verbal Skill"  will be essentially visible.

In jobs such as Sales, engineering - this has implications only to an extent of connecting to customers or peers. But mostly your qualification matters the most here. In many cases like Call centers it becomes important to be extremely well spoken, but in that case those folks either have their own test or training during job. In case of literary oriented jobs Such as news reporting etc. again they have very different expectations and evaluate you accordingly.

In all, the recruiter knows what they are looking for and will evaluate it depending on the critical need of job. So external certificates, course are good for improving yourself but unless it is visible in how you present yourself in the interview, and that skill is visible, it isn't really a big deal to put up a score.

Answer (score 2):

What employers look for when they want someone with "excellent communication skills" has little to do with anything that would appear on a test unless you are talking about a position that requires writing official documents like documentation, press releases, etc.  For an engineering position, "good communications skills" means that you can clearly describe what you are doing, what you intend to do, and what you did, and that when you have a conversation, no one leaves the room confused as to what was agreed to.

I have known plenty of people who were great communicators despite being mediocre English speakers.  I have also known plenty of completely fluent people who were horrible communicators.  "Communications skills" doesn't mean you can find the best synonym to "dyspeptic".  It means that you understand what others mean, and can clearly express your ideas.

Though to be honest, when I see "good communications skills" on a resume, I ignore it because *everybody* says that.  How true that is usually comes out in the interview anyway.

Now if your applying for a position as a copyeditor, maybe it is different.

Answer (score 1):

So I searched online, and it appears that yes - it's unnecessary and tacky/weird. It does not mean much to the interviewer. And it might appear like "showing-off" - so I won't put the score/info.

It also is irrelevant, as a measure of how a person would fit into a company.